# Sending common values to google analytics trekking

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a recommended way to send additional values as part of the google analytics data? I need to pass following additional values to the Google Analytics which can help business.

These additional values are not page dependent and should be sent to GA in all cases.

This is how it has been implemented by someone but seems not to work

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', googleAnalyticsTrackingId]);
_gaq.push(['_setBrand', brand]);
_gaq.push(['_setCatalog', catalog]);
_gaq.push(['_setCountry', country]);
```

When using above code, I can see following error in the console (I am using GA debug plugin)

```
Called method "_setBrand" threw exception.TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
ga_debug.js:30 Called method "_setCatalog" threw exception.TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

I looked into the document and seems that we can create custom attribute like

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
      1,                   // This custom var is set to slot #1.  Required parameter.
      'brand',           // The top-level name for your online content categories.  Required parameter.
      brand,  // Sets the value of "Section" to "Life & Style" for this particular aricle.  Required parameter.
      3                    // Sets the scope to page-level.  Optional parameter.
   ]);
```

I tried this approach but unable to see any values (Brand) being passed to GA.
Can someone help me to understand the correct way or point me to documentation to do this as I have very limited knowledge of GA tagging API?

Comment: Custom vars are deprecated. You would have to use custom dimensions, and for that you'd have to update your tracking code. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets

Comment: @EikePierstorff: We are still using ga.js is a legacy library and can't change it at this moment

Comment: I am not sure if sending custom vars is still supported. If so then you will find them in the Audience/Custom/Custom Variables report in GA and can use them in segments, custom reports or as secondary dimension. Your code looks alright. The first example did not work because the first argument to the _gaq.push is a method name (to which the following arguments are passed as parameters) and "_setCatalog" is not an existing method in the ga.js code.

Comment: @EikePierstorff: I was able to find this custom var on the dashboard :)